# Spring Security How to Accept Access Token from OAuth2SSo server?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have one Spring project that uses a third party authentication using `@EnableOAuth2Sso`. I want this to protect another project that is a "Resource Server" (am I using this term correctly?). How would I set this up? I've annotated it with `@EnableResourceServer`. When a request gets forwarded from the "Authorization Server" (not sure about this term either since I'm using OAuth2Sso instead of my own Authentication Server with `@EnableAuthenticationServer`) I'm getting an `Invalid access token` message. When I access the resource endpoint directly I get `Full authentication is required to access this resourceunauthorized` message.

(I'm using Zuul and Eureka as well but I don't think it's important to the question.)

Comment: Can you show us the configuration file? where you set the clientId, accessTokenUri, userAuthorizationUri, etc.

Comment: On the OAuth2Sso server or the resource server? I know I have the OAuth2Sso server working proper because I'm receiving info from the third party. And my resource server doesn't have those properties set... I'm not exactly sure how to configure it for my OAuth2Sso server.

Comment: It should have that some kind of configuration. Have you tried this? - https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_social_login_manual The configuration could be on a properties file or yml or annotated

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo at the end. I meant I wasn't sure how to configure my resource server with my OAuth2Sso server. The link you provided is to configure the OAuth2Sso server with a lower level to be more explicit. But I don't think I need that since I'm receiving data from the third party already. I need to configure the resource server to accept access tokens from the OAuth2Sso server.

Comment: Unless, instead of annotating it with `@EnableResourceServer` I use the `@EnableOAuth2Sso` or `@EnableOAuth2Client` annotation.